# how to reference many variables inside dataframe in long expression

Tags: r, expression

I have the following df

```
> structure(f)
   p c  at cu z   m  A   ps dc w al  W    b  t  s  u re fs1 fs2 uc
1 21 7  12 43 1 0.5 10 22.3  5 5  8 NA 0.782 NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA
```

and another df containing the expressions/formulas to calculate the NA values in f

```
> structure(formulas)
   W           t
2 p*z*al p*z*sin(b)
       s       u         re         
2 p*z*cos(b) m*ps*z c+((s-u)*tan(at)
```

f could have multiple rows so I would just like to apply each formula to all rows of each column.
For example to calculate W I could try

```
f$W=f$p*f$z*f$al
```

However I would like to know if there is a way to automate all this. I would like to convert the expressions in formulas and then apply them to calculate the corresponding variable in f. Is there a way to reference columns in a df without repeating df$ when evaluating an expression?
I know I can use eval(parse(text="formulas[1,1]")) to turn my strings into an expression but here I am working on a whole df column.

Comment: I would suggest minimalistic example. The problem is not in the complexity of formulas, it is accessing proper data determined by text string? Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @A.Val. I will edit to make this simpler to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, thanks to Frank, it turns out this method was unnecessarily convoluted, as `eval` can take an `envir`-argument.

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=5:1)
```

Therefore, we can make our formulas like this:

```
formulas = quote(data.frame(a_plus_b = a+b, a_min_b = a-b))
```

Evaluating is then easy:

```
out <- cbind(dat, eval(formulas, dat))


 > out
  a b a_plus_b a_min_b
1 1 5        6      -4
2 2 4        6      -2
3 3 3        6       0
4 4 2        6       2
5 5 1        6       4
```

Old approach using strings:

```
formulas <- data.frame(a_plus_b="a+b",
                       a_min_b = "a-b",stringsAsFactors=F)

out <- cbind(dat,lapply(formulas, function(x){with(dat, eval(parse(text=x)))}))
```

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand how this works. I don't want to manually type all formulas like you did in formulas = quote(data.frame(a_plus_b = a+b, a_min_b = a-b)). Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's dummydata, to demonstrate the principle. Your formulas are already in a dataframe, no?

Comment: I do but even the single eval it's not working. My formulas are factors

```eval(parse(text="formred[,1]"),envir=f)
[1] p*z*al
Levels:  p*z*al
> eval(parse(text="formred[1,1]"),envir=f)
[1] p*z*al
Levels:  p*z*al

Comment: the data.frame you created it's just strings I imagine, so perhaps this is the problem, because mine is factors

Comment: Then convert to character, or prevent factors being made when de data is imported.

Comment: I tried but eval is still not working, somehow the envir does not work. Keep returning just the string "p*z*al" without evaluating

Comment: If you look at the first part of the answer, there is no parse there (I'm on my phone, so can't tinker)

Comment: ok I solved it, I actually needed to convert to strings and then use parse with text, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this `data.table` way. Probably can get rid of for loop too. But somehow it doesn't work for me. Will update if I find a way.

```
df <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), z = NA, w = NA)
df2 <- data.table(x = NA, y = NA, z = "cos(x) + sin(y)", w = "x * y")
varnames <- colnames(df2)[!sapply(df2[1,], is.na)]
for(i in varnames){
  df[,c(i) := with(df, eval(parse(text = with(df2, get(i)))))]
}
```

Comment: I think the data.table way would be `formulas = quote(\`:=\`(z = cos(x) + sin(y), w = x*y)); df[, eval(formulas)]` (if working with expressions instead of strings)

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. It fills all the variables with 2.

Comment: That is certainly weird. Try a re-run on fresh R Session. And make sure you have updated R / data.table package.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` way:

```
require(dplyr)
f <- f %>% mutate(W = p*z*al, t = p*z*sin(b), s = p*z*cos(b),
                  u = m*ps*z, re = c+((s-u)*tan(at))
```